# rtorrent: 'Tracker Timeout' caused by IPtables

Tags: iptables, timeout, rtorrent

I'm trying to secure my rtorrent-running-homeserver with IPtables. With the aim to allow only incoming connections to the rtorrent port 6890 and 5292 for ftp (both are forwarded by the router), I wrote the following rules:

```
# Allows all Connections from localhost (necessary for scgi port 5000 of rtorrent):
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p udp -j ACCEPT


# Allows all Connections from 192.168.2.* (local network) and 192.168.10.* (local vpn network)
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -p tcp -j ACCEPT


# Allows all input-Connections on port 6890 (rtorrent) and 5292 (ftp)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6890 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5292 -j ACCEPT


# Blocks everything else
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j DROP
```

If the rules are active, I get the error `'Tracker: Timeout was reached'`. Without everything is running like a charm. So it seems to blame on my iptables-rules.

Is there anyone who may help?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

which will allow all packages in already existing connections.

Also, instead of your last rule to block everything else, I would recommend setting a policy:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```